# TypeError : can't convert Pathname into String : Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, typeerror, pathname

I am getting error while running following code in rails at line:

```
@api_key = "XXXXX"
api_secret = "XXXX"

@opentok = OpenTok::OpenTokSDK.new @api_key, api_secret
@opentok.api_url = 'https://staging.tokbox.com/hl'

@session = @opentok.create_session request.remote_addr # this line

@token = @opentok.generate_token :session_id => @session
```

After running code I got:

```
TypeError in ShowsController#action
can't convert Pathname into String
```

I'm using:

```
ruby -version : ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]
rails -version: 3.0.9
gem -version: 1.7.2
```

Comment: Where is the error arising in that code?

Comment: What doesthe "request"-variable contain? Is that the source of the error?

Comment: Hi, Romain and Allan Norgaard , At the line @opentok.create_session, I am getting this error. And request variable contains the object of ActionDispatch.